# Get the current category with Magento version 1.4.2

Tags: magento

I have always used :

```
$current_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
```

to get the current category in Magento version 1.4.1.1 but this isn't working anymore with Magento version 1.4.2

How can I get it with the 1.4.2 version ?

Comment: The snippet is even used by the Magento core in Magento 1.4.2. Hence,it really should work. Are you sure that your surrounding code is correct? :-)

Comment: Yes, it always returns 'NULL' !! :(

Comment: Are you sure that `Mage::register('current_category', $category);` was called before your code?

Comment: @jamapag  : No, what's the variable "$category" in your snippet ?

Comment: `$category` is a category object that will be current category. This code you can find in `Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php` in `_initCategory` method for example.

Comment: if you are trying to call this outside product view or catalog list then AFAIK it wouldn't work.

Comment: Stop writing tags in titles please.

Answer (score 0):

Mage::register 
must have been called somewhere within your code before you can come back later anywhere to call 
Mage::registry

Also,   when you say "getting the current category"

what exactly do you mean, get the current category a particular product now belongs or what?